# Programmatically Change data in a core data file

Tags: core-data

Hello All & Thanks in Advance!

I am a noob with Core Data and I need to change data in one of my fields which is named: recid.

I have created a index which again is: recid as int 16 in my core data model.

What I am needing to do is fetch the record and changed recid from we will say 5 to 1 how would I go about doing this?

Here is the code I have built so far & I will take care of my loop after I understand how to change the data in the record.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSMenu *theMenu;
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"TheJournal_16x16x32"]];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
    [theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"The Journal" action:@selector(showTheWindow:) keyEquivalent:@"W"];
    [theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"Q"];
    [statusItem setMenu:theMenu];
    [theMenu release];

    NSUInteger count;
    count = 0;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    count = [prefs integerForKey:@"recid"];
    NSLog(@"counter is >>>>%lu",(unsigned long)count);
    [prefs setInteger:count forKey:@"recid"];
    count++;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs1 setInteger:count forKey:@"recid"];
    NSLog(@"counter is >>>>%lu",(unsigned long)count);

    // How I fetch the record & change the value from 5 to 1?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a fetch request? Apple provides [detailed documentation with sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1).

Comment: Also, your code snippet doesn't use Core Data at all. Where are you using it? What does that code do?

Comment: Where is your core data object 'record'? All I see is your use of User Defaults...

Comment: I have attempted to use a fetch request from the example provided by you in the link but it is making no sense to me at all.

Comment: @Tom Harrington I have tried this code for the fetch request:     fetchRequest.resultType = NSCountResultType;
    NSError *error = nil;

    [fetchRequest setValue:fetchRequest forKey:@"recid"];
    
    [managedObjectContext save:&error];
    count++; Now I am getting the error: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key recid.

Comment: Are you using Core Data anywhere else in your project? Your code snippet does not include anything related to Core Data.

Comment: @peter, I have my xcdatamodel setup up with subclasses.

Comment: Please get some tutorials and documentation about Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample that may help you. In this example, the `YourManagedClass` Core Data entity uses a UUID string as a unique record identifier. The extension contains a static function that fetches the unique record, sets the new `recid` value and then saves the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

class YourManagedClass: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var uuid: String?
    @NSManaged var recid: NSNumber?
}

extension YourManagedClass {
    static func set(recID: Int16, forObject uuid: String, `in` context:     NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<YourManagedClass>(entityName: "YourManagedClass")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid = %@", argumentArray: [uuid])

        let object: YourManagedClass
        do {
            let objects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            guard let foundObject = objects.first else {
                return
            }

            object = foundObject
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
            return
        }

        object.recid = NSNumber(value: recID)

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

You would then call this function with a reference to your `NSManagedObjectContext` ('context' here):

```swift
YourManagedClass.set(recID: 15, forObject: "909455F3-C812-4399-83B4-F96A5C32A71D", in: context)
```